# Eloquent não retorna os mesmos resultados que o SQL

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho esse código *SQL* que ao executar direto no banco funciona normal, mas tive que convertê-lo para o formato do *laravel*. Ele executa, mas não retorna nenhum resultado.

Onde estou errando? Parece que o problema está ali nos `where` da `subquery`, onde ele pega as colunas da *query* principal, pois alterei os campos por valores manuais e funcionou, fiz assim:

```
->where('m2.remetente_id', '=', 1)
->where('m2.destinatario_id', '=', 2);
```

SQL

```
SELECT
  m1.id
FROM
  mensagens m1
WHERE
  m1.destinatario_id = 1 AND m1.created_at < (
    SELECT
      m2.created_at
    FROM
      mensagens m2
    WHERE
      m2.remetente_id = m1.destinatario_id AND m2.destinatario_id = m1.remetente_id)
GROUP BY
    m1.id
```

LARAVEL

```
Mensagem::where('destinatario_id', 1)
            ->where('created_at', '<', function($q) {
                $q->from('mensagens AS m2')
                  ->select('created_at')
                  ->where('m2.remetente_id', '=', 'mensagens.destinatario_id')
                  ->where('m2.destinatario_id', '=', 'mensagens.remetente_id');
            })
            ->select('id')
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Mas qual é o sentido da `created_at` ser menor que a subquery?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters preciso listar a primeira mensagem de cada conversa do usuário logado, mas apenas aquelas em que ele não iniciou a conversa, por isso faço essa comparação de datas

Comment: @WallaceMaxters tentei usar o DB::select pra executar o código e funcionou, o problema é só quando faço daquela forma que mencionei no post. Tens alguma ideia do que pode ser o problema?

Comment: Resolvido! Troquei o where por whereColumn e funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

Caso alguém também não consiga comparar as colunas da `query` principal com as da `subquery`, foi resolvido da seguinte forma:

É necessário trocar o `where` por `whereColumn`. Este é um método usado especificamente para verificar se duas colunas são iguais.

Exemplo:

```
->whereColumn('m2.remetente_id', '=', 'mensagens.destinatario_id')
->whereColumn('m2.destinatario_id', '=', 'mensagens.remetente_id');
```